# Dividing project to .h and .cpp

Tags: c++, header, include, addition

I wanted to divide my project into smaller parts cause it started to be unreadable(1000+ lines) and i have some problem with specified .h and .cpp that need to use definitons defined in other files.

Project contains following files:

main.cpp
RPG.h and .cpp
Hero.h and .cpp
Globaldefs.h and .cpp

```
#ifndef Hero_h
#define Hero_h
#include "Globaldefs.h"
#include "RPG.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

extern class NPC;
extern class Inventory;

class Hero
{
protected:
    (...)
    Inventory inventory;
    (...)
public:
    vector<Mob*>::iterator TryAttack(vector <Mob*>& monsters, int & number);
    vector<NPC*>::iterator TryTalk(vector <NPC*>& _NPCs, int & number);

};
(...)
#endif
```

declaration above is from Hero.h file and compilator finds error in line Inventory inventory; (that class is outside, declared in RPG.h and defined in RPG.cpp): 'Hero::inventory' uses undefined class 'Inventory' RPG d:\programming\rpg\rpg\rpg\hero.h   23  I completely don't understand why Mob(other class from RPG.h and .cpp) work properly and NPC defined as extern(too in RPG.h) as well.

```
    #ifndef RPG_h
#define RPG_h
#include "Globaldefs.h"
#include "Hero.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Mob;
class NPC;
class Fight;
class Item;
extern class Hero;
(...)
class Meat : public Item
{
(...)
public:
    virtual void ActivateEffect(Hero* _hero) { _hero->AddHp(15); }; 
};
#endif
```

this is RPG.h file, and there, compilator says that something went wrong in line

```
virtual void ActivateEffect(Hero* _hero) { _hero->AddHp(15); };
```

there is: use of undefined type 'Hero'  RPG d:\programming\rpg\rpg\rpg\rpg.h    97  and left of '->AddHp' must point to class/struct/union/generic type RPG d:\programming\rpg\rpg\rpg\rpg.h    97

i reserched many sites, but everywhere people has problems with simple adding files to main.cpp, not making internal connections beetween files.

Comment: main.cpp
RPG.h and .cpp
Hero.h and .cpp
Globaldefs.h and .cpp that are obviously not part of code :D fckin editor dont allow me to post question without marked those as code

Answer (score 3):

Inclusion guards prevent you to include `RPG.h` in `Hero.h` and vice-versa.

What you did is to forward declare `Hero` in `RPG.h`, which is good.

But then you did:

```
virtual void ActivateEffect(Hero* _hero) { _hero->AddHp(15); };
```

and the compiler needs to know the structure of `Hero` class to link it to `AddHp` method. You just cannot do that.

Do that instead (just declare the method):

```
virtual void ActivateEffect(Hero* _hero);
```

And remove the `#include "Hero.h"` line.

Then in the `RPG.cpp` file do:

```
#include "Hero.h"
void RPG::ActivateEffect(Hero* _hero) { _hero->AddHp(15); }
```

We don't see the code for the `Inventory` problem, but I suppose that's the same problem.

To summarize:

- you can include file `A.h` in file `B.h` but in that case you cannot include file `B.h` in `A.h`
- but you can forward declare `class B` in `A.h` and reference the pointer/reference on that class, as long as you don't try to use `B` methods in the header file.
- to use `B` methods in `A` object, just include `B.h` in `A.cpp` and have access to all `B` method in `A.cpp`. Some inline methods cannot be implemented in the .h file when they use methods/members of `B`

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency between RPG.h and Hero.h, and RPG.h line 97, only the forward declaration (`extern class Hero;`) is visible so you can only reference pointers and references to whole `Hero` objects and cannot reference *members* of `Hero`.

The circular dependency may itself indicate poor design in any case.